# Probability distribution $P(X=k)=kp^k$

Tags: probability

I have a probability mass function of a random variable which takes value k with probability $k p^k$ (in my case $p=1/12$), where $k$ is at least $2$.  The probability of $k=1$ is then I believe $1-(\frac{p}{(1-p)^2}-p)$ after computing $\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}{kp^k}$ (though I may have made a mistake).  Either way, is this a well known distribution? I'm a pretty big dummy when it comes to probability.

Comment: $\propto xe^{-\lambda x}$ is pdf of a continuous gamma-distribution, so this seems like a discrete analog of it.

Comment: I only have expressions for the probability for $k$ at least 2, and the variables takes an integer value 1 or higher.  The value at 1 is then just whatever makes the total sum 1.  I might have evaluated the sum incorrectly though. And I guess I'm assuming $p$ is sufficiently small (in my case I believe it is).

Comment: @Mas For $p$ sufficiently small (which includes $\frac 1 {12}$), the total mass of $[2,\infty)$ is less than $1$, so you can always pick $p_1$ to normalize.

Comment: Oh, ok...$p_1$, you are right @A.S.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this answer your "question", anyway. We have that

$$\sum kp^k\delta k=\frac{kp^k}{p-1}-\sum\frac{p^{k+1}}{p-1}\delta k=\frac{kp^k}{p-1}-\frac{p^{k+1}}{(p-1)^2}+K$$

Then taking limits for some $p\in[0,1)$

$$\sum_{k\ge 2}kp^k=\frac{(p-1)kp^k-p^{k+1}}{(p-1)^2}\Biggr|_{k=2}^{\infty}=\frac{p^3-(p-1)2p^2}{(p-1)^2}=\frac{p^2(2-p)}{(p-1)^2}$$

Then we have that

$$\frac{p^2(2-p)}{(p-1)^2}+p_1=1\implies p_1=1-\frac{p^2(2-p)}{(p-1)^2}$$

Then the probability mass function for some "enough small" $p$ is

$$f(k)=\begin{cases}&1-\frac{p^2(2-p)}{(p-1)^2} &,\text{ for }k=1\\&kp^k &,\text{ for }k>1\\&0 &,\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$